# Typescript: use ReturnType of array of functions (edited)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to type the following function:

```js
function foo(input, modifier, merge) {
    return merge(...modifier.map(m => m(input)));
}
```

The objective is to have the correct types for the parameters of the `merge` function.

Context:

- `modifier` is an array of function with a single parameter of the type of `typeof input` and a different return type for each function
- `merge` is a function, which has `modifier.length` parameters, with the parameter at position n having the same type as the return type of the function `modifier[n]` and returns a singe (generic) value

How can this be done?

---

### Edit: Alternative Question

Possible with objects (`Record<K,V>`):

```js
// for Functions (here type Func)
type Func = () => any;

// a mapping of a string key to an function can be created
type FuncMap = Record<string, Func>;

// for this mapping you can create a mapping to the return types of each function
type ReturnTypeMap<T extends FuncMap> = { [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[K]> }
```

Is something like this also possible for arrays, based on the position instead of a object key?

---

This is my attempt at the typing the function, but i don't know how to use ReturnType in combination with arrays:

```js
function foo<I, M extends Array<(input: I) => any>, O>(
    input: I,
    modifier: M,
    merge: (...args: ReturnType<M>) => O
    //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is not working, since relation to each item is missing
): O {
    return merge(...modifier.map(m => m(input)));
}
```

Comment: What is `modifier` supposed to be? An array of functions but should they be? And what is `merge`?

Comment: Updated question to clarify `modifier` and `merge`

Comment: OK, so you can have something like `input = "foo"` and them `modifier.map(m => m(input))`  might produce, say `[42, "bar", true]`. The `merge` function is then supposed to take all these and produce some single value. If I'm reading the description correctly, with this example, `merge` should produce `boolean` as that's the last value. Is that correct?

Comment: No, the return type of merge is generic; updated question

Comment: But, the rest of your assumtions is correct

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this I think:

```js
type ExtractReturnTypes<T extends readonly ((i: any) => any)[]> = [
  ... {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ((i: any) => infer R) ? R : never
  }
];

function foo<I, M extends readonly ((i: I) => any)[], O>(
  input: I,
  modifiers: M,
  merge: (...args: ExtractReturnTypes<M>) => O
) {}

foo(
  1,
  [(i: number) => 5, (i: number) => 'b' as const] as const,
  // a has type: number
  // b has type: 'b'
  (a, b) => 'test'
);
```

Comment: How do I use this?

Comment: I've edited my answer, I think it doesn't require defining a type like I did previously.

Comment: This does not work, since every function in `modifier` can have a differen return type. I have updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: `ExtractReturnTypes` - very clever!

Alternative implementation: `type Fn = (...args: any) => any; 
type RT<A extends ReadonlyArray<Fn>> = A extends [infer H, ...infer R] ? H extends Fn ? R extends Fn[] ? [ReturnType<H>, ...RT<R>] : [] : [] : []`